# Download n Bytes Starting at x Position of HTTP File In VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I've seen many samples dealing with downloading HTTP files through VBScript into ADO buffers, but I can't figure out how to tweak those samples to work with what I need: start downloading at given byte position x and download n bytes. I figure this has to do with the following call:

`object.Open "GET", "url", asyncValue`

The above code attempts to download the entire file. So can I change this, or is there a different approach altogether that lets me achieve what I need in VBScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh453379) and set the `Range` header:

```
url = "..."

first = 123
last  = 321

Set req = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
req.Open "GET", url, False
req.setRequestHeader "Range", "bytes=" & first & "-" & last
req.Send

If req.Status = 200 Then WScript.Echo req.ResponseText
```

You can retrieve the remote file in chunks by setting

```
first = iteration * chunksize
last  = first + chunksize
```

Or you can retrieve the remainder of a file by omitting the `last` value:

```
first = 123
last  = ""
```

If the remote file is binary, you may need to save it to a file like this:

```
Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Open
stream.Type = 1 'binary
stream.Write req.responseBody
stream.SaveToFile "C:\out.file"
stream.Close
```